# Incompatible shapes: [16,8,1] vs. [16,1] [[{{node loss_3/dense_7_loss/MeanSquaredError/sub}}]]

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to predict the quantity of c02 using LSTM model in RNN deep learning

```
    import numpy as np
    from numpy import zeros, newaxis
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import scipy
    from scipy import stats
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow import keras
    from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, layers, callbacks
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Input
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    from sklearn import preprocessing 
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
    from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize
    from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
    register_matplotlib_converters()
    import seaborn as sns
    
    df1 = pd.read_csv('CO2_O2_0_1.csv', header = 0)
    1
    df1.head()
    Wavelength (cm-1)   CO2:O2=0:1 (Absorbance)
    0   1000.409    0.000104
    1   1000.891    0.000085
    2   1001.373    0.000053
    3   1001.855    0.000111
    4   1002.337    0.000251
    1
    df3 = pd.read_csv('CO2_O2_1_0.csv', header = 0)
    2
    df3.head()
    Wavelength (cm-1)   CO2:O2=1:0 (Absorbance)
    0   1000.409    0.000148
    1   1000.891    0.000137
    2   1001.373    0.000052
    3   1001.855    0.000004
    4   1002.337    0.000108
    1
    df2 = pd.read_csv('CO2_O2_15_1.csv', header = 0)
    2
    df2.head()
    Wavelength (cm-1)   CO2:O2=15:1 (Absorbance)
    0   1000.409    -0.000160
    1   1000.891    -0.000038
    2   1001.373    -0.000192
    3   1001.855    -0.000356
    4   1002.337    -0.000081
    1
    df4 = pd.read_csv('CO2_O2_1_1.csv')
    2
    df4.head()
    Wavelength (cm-1)   CO2:O2=1:1 (Absorbance)
    0   1000.409    -0.000105
    1   1000.891    -0.000178
    2   1001.373    -0.000178
    3   1001.855    -0.000148
    4   1002.337    -0.000117
    1
    df5 = pd.read_csv('CO2_O2_1_3.csv')
    2
    df5.head()
    Wavelength (cm-1)   CO2:O2=1:3 (Absorbance)
    0   1000.409    0.000109
    1   1000.891    0.000107
    2   1001.373    0.000184
    3   1001.855    0.000163
    4   1002.337    0.000012
    1
    df6 = pd.read_csv('CO2_O2_1_6.csv')
    2
    df6.head()
    Wavelength (cm-1)   CO2:O2=1:6 (Absorbance)
    0   1000.409    0.000100
    1   1000.891    0.000238
    2   1001.373    0.000313
    3   1001.855    0.000234
    4   1002.337    0.000122
    1
    df7 = pd.read_csv('CO2_O2_3_1.csv')
    2
    df7.head()
    Wavelength (cm-1)   CO2:O2=3:1 (Absorbance)
    0   1000.409    0.000048
    1   1000.891    0.000033
    2   1001.373    -0.000079
    3   1001.855    -0.000263
    4   1002.337    -0.000228
    1
    df8 = pd.read_csv('CO2_O2_5_1.csv')
    2
    df8.head()
    Wavelength (cm-1)   CO2:O2=5:1 (Absorbance)
    0   1000.409    8.410000e-05
    1   1000.891    -1.580000e-04
    2   1001.373    -6.250000e-07
    3   1001.855    1.560000e-04
    4   1002.337    4.010000e-05
    1
    df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8], ignore_index=True, axis = 0, sort = False)
    2
    df.head()
    Wavelength (cm-1)   CO2:O2=0:1 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=15:1 (Absorbance)    CO2:O2=1:0 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=1:1 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=1:3 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=1:6 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=3:1 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=5:1 (Absorbance)
    0   1000.409    0.000104    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    1   1000.891    0.000085    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    2   1001.373    0.000053    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    3   1001.855    0.000111    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    4   1002.337    0.000251    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    1
    df.shape
    (1344, 9)
    Missing Value Imputation
    1
    df['Wavelength (cm-1)'].fillna(value = df['Wavelength (cm-1)'].mean(), inplace = True)
    2
    df['CO2:O2=0:1 (Absorbance)'].fillna(value = df['CO2:O2=0:1 (Absorbance)'].mean(), inplace = True)
    3
    df['CO2:O2=15:1 (Absorbance)'].fillna(value = df['CO2:O2=15:1 (Absorbance)'].mean(), inplace = True)
    4
    df['CO2:O2=1:0 (Absorbance)'].fillna(value = df['CO2:O2=1:0 (Absorbance)'].mean(), inplace = True)
    5
    df['CO2:O2=1:1 (Absorbance)'].fillna(value = df['CO2:O2=1:1 (Absorbance)'].mean(), inplace = True)
    6
    df['CO2:O2=1:3 (Absorbance)'].fillna(value = df['CO2:O2=1:3 (Absorbance)'].mean(), inplace = True)
    7
    df['CO2:O2=1:6 (Absorbance)'].fillna(value = df['CO2:O2=1:6 (Absorbance)'].mean(), inplace = True)
    8
    df['CO2:O2=3:1 (Absorbance)'].fillna(value = df['CO2:O2=3:1 (Absorbance)'].mean(), inplace = True)
    9
    df['CO2:O2=5:1 (Absorbance)'].fillna(value = df['CO2:O2=5:1 (Absorbance)'].mean(), inplace = True)
    1
    df.info()
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    RangeIndex: 1344 entries, 0 to 1343
    Data columns (total 9 columns):
    Wavelength (cm-1)           1344 non-null float64
    CO2:O2=0:1 (Absorbance)     1344 non-null float64
    CO2:O2=15:1 (Absorbance)    1344 non-null float64
    CO2:O2=1:0 (Absorbance)     1344 non-null float64
    CO2:O2=1:1 (Absorbance)     1344 non-null float64
    CO2:O2=1:3 (Absorbance)     1344 non-null float64
    CO2:O2=1:6 (Absorbance)     1344 non-null float64
    CO2:O2=3:1 (Absorbance)     1344 non-null float64
    CO2:O2=5:1 (Absorbance)     1344 non-null float64
    dtypes: float64(9)
    memory usage: 94.6 KB
    1
    df.head()
    Wavelength (cm-1)   CO2:O2=0:1 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=15:1 (Absorbance)    CO2:O2=1:0 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=1:1 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=1:3 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=1:6 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=3:1 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=5:1 (Absorbance)
    0   1000.409    0.000104    0.000624    0.000282    0.001511    0.00179 0.002626    0.001083    0.000797
    1   1000.891    0.000085    0.000624    0.000282    0.001511    0.00179 0.002626    0.001083    0.000797
    2   1001.373    0.000053    0.000624    0.000282    0.001511    0.00179 0.002626    0.001083    0.000797
    3   1001.855    0.000111    0.000624    0.000282    0.001511    0.00179 0.002626    0.001083    0.000797
    4   1002.337    0.000251    0.000624    0.000282    0.001511    0.00179 0.002626    0.001083    0.000797
    Outliers Treatment
    1
    #df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
    1
    df.shape
    (1344, 9)
    x,y split
    1
    x = df.loc[:,df.columns!="Wavelength (cm-1)"]
    2
    x.shape
    (1344, 8)
    1
    y = df['Wavelength (cm-1)']
    2
    type(y)
    pandas.core.series.Series
    1
    y.shape
    (1344,)
    1
    x_train_full, x_test, y_train_full, y_test = train_test_split(x, y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
    2
    ​
    3
    x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(x_train_full, y_train_full, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
    4
    x_train.head()
    CO2:O2=0:1 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=15:1 (Absorbance)    CO2:O2=1:0 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=1:1 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=1:3 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=1:6 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=3:1 (Absorbance) CO2:O2=5:1 (Absorbance)
    1169    0.005092    0.000624    0.000282    0.001511    0.001790    0.002626    -0.000106   0.000797
    1072    0.005092    0.000624    0.000282    0.001511    0.001790    0.002626    0.000616    0.000797
    784 0.005092    0.000624    0.000282    0.001511    -0.000055   0.002626    0.001083    0.000797
    375 0.005092    0.000624    -0.000137   0.001511    0.001790    0.002626    0.001083    0.000797
    305 0.005092    -0.000090   0.000282    0.001511    0.001790    0.002626    0.001083    0.000797
    1
    np.random.seed(42)
    2
    tf.random.set_random_seed(42)
    1
    x_train.shape
    (860, 8)
    1
    x_valid.shape
    (215, 8)
    1
    x_valid_3d = x_valid.values.reshape(x_valid.shape[0],8,1).astype('float32')
    2
    x_valid_3d.shape
    (215, 8, 1)
    1
    y_valid.shape
    (215,)
    1
    #y_valid_3d = y_valid.values.reshape(y_valid.shape[0],1,1).astype('float32')
    2
    #y_valid_3d
    1
    x_test.shape
    (269, 8)
    1
    y_train.shape
    (860,)
    1
    y_test.shape
    (269,)
    1
    x_train_3d = x_train.values.reshape(x_train.shape[0],8,1).astype('float32')
    2
    x_test_3d = x_test.values.reshape(x_test.shape[0],8,1).astype('float32')
    1
    x_test_3d.shape
    (269, 8, 1)
    1
    sc = StandardScaler().fit(x_train)
    2
    sc_train_std = sc.transform(x_train)
    3
    sc_test_std = sc.transform(x_test)
    4
    sc_test_std
    array([[ 1.78192582e-02, -5.73877445e-01, -1.17600227e-02, ...,
             6.23458297e-03,  2.07732728e-02,  1.94397475e-02],
           [ 1.78192582e-02,  8.53034545e+00, -1.17600227e-02, ...,
             6.23458297e-03,  2.07732728e-02,  1.94397475e-02],
           [ 1.78192582e-02,  5.48432794e-03, -1.17600227e-02, ...,
            -1.47457945e+00,  2.07732728e-02,  1.94397475e-02],
           ...,
           [ 1.78192582e-02,  5.48432794e-03, -9.56460901e-01, ...,
             6.23458297e-03,  2.07732728e-02,  1.94397475e-02],
           [ 1.78192582e-02,  5.48432794e-03, -1.17600227e-02, ...,
             6.23458297e-03,  2.07732728e-02, -1.51494627e+00],
           [-1.38528609e+00,  5.48432794e-03, -1.17600227e-02, ...,
             6.23458297e-03,  2.07732728e-02,  1.94397475e-02]])
    1
    sc_test_std.shape
    (269, 8)
    1
    sc_train_std.shape
    (860, 8)
    ,1
    1
    model = Sequential()
    2
    model.add(LSTM(30, activation = 'relu', input_shape=[8,1], return_sequences = True))
    3
    model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
    4
    model.add(Dense(1))
    1
    model.summary()
    _________________________________________________________________
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
    =================================================================
    lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 8, 30)             3840      
    _________________________________________________________________
    dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 8, 30)             930       
    _________________________________________________________________
    dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 8, 1)              31        
    =================================================================
    Total params: 4,801
    Trainable params: 4,801
    Non-trainable params: 0
    _________________________________________________________________
    1
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    1
    checkpoint_cb = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("Best_Model.h5", save_best_only=True)
    1
    x_valid_3d.shape
    (215, 8, 1)
    1
    x_train_3d.shape
    (860, 8, 1)
    16
    1
    model.fit(x_train_3d,y_train, batch_size=16, epochs =5, validation_data=(x_valid_3d,y_valid), callbacks=[checkpoint_cb], verbose=1)
    Train on 860 samples, validate on 215 samples
    Epoch 1/5
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-74-1e4223a8a839> in <module>()
    ----> 1 model.fit(x_train_3d,y_train, batch_size=16, epochs =5, validation_data=(x_valid_3d,y_valid), callbacks=[checkpoint_cb], verbose=1)
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
        878           initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
        879           steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    --> 880           validation_steps=validation_steps)
        881 
        882   def evaluate(self,
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, mode, validation_in_fit, **kwargs)
        327 
        328         # Get outputs.
    --> 329         batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
        330         if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
        331           batch_outs = [batch_outs]
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
       3074 
       3075     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
    -> 3076                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
       3077     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
       3078     return nest.pack_sequence_as(self._outputs_structure,
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       1437           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
       1438               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
    -> 1439               run_metadata_ptr)
       1440         if run_metadata:
       1441           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
        526             None, None,
        527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
    --> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
        529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
        530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to
    
    InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [16,8,1] vs. [16,1]
         [[{{node loss_3/dense_7_loss/MeanSquaredError/sub}}]]
```

Comment: What is your question? See [ask].

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).